# RegExp issues - character limit and whitespace ignoring

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a string that can have any number of characters, a comma, and then 2 characters. I'm having some issues. Here's what I have:

```
var str="ab,cdf"; 
var patt1=new RegExp("[A-z]{2,}[,][A-z]{2}");
if(patt1.test(str)) {
    alert("true");
}
else {
    alert("false");
}
```

I would expect this to return false, as I have the `{2}` limit on characters after the comma and this string has three characters. When I run the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmmyS/z2fTr/), though, it returns true. My (admittedly limited) understanding of RegExp indicates that `{2,}` is at least 2, and `{2}` is exactly two, so I'm not sure why three characters after the comma are still returning true.

I also need to be able to ignore a possible whitespace between the comma and the remaining two characters. (In other words, I want it to return true if they have 2+ characters before the comma and two after it - the two after it not including any whitespace that the user may have entered.)

So all of these should return true:

```
var str = "ab, cd";
var str = "abc, cd";
var str = "ab,cd";
var str = "abc,dc";
```

I've tried adding the `\S` indicator after the comma like this:

```
var patt1=new RegExp("[A-z]{2,}[,]\S[A-z]{2}");
```

But then the string returns false all the time, even when I have it set to `ab, cd`, which should return true.

What am I missing?

Comment: [Your fiddle's code](http://jsfiddle.net/EmmyS/z2fTr/) is actually different from [your question's code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17751150/578288). It says `{2,}` instead of `{2}`. But that's not the problem; when I fix that, your fiddle still alerts `true`.

Comment: Your problem with `\S` (apart from the fact that it should be `\s`) is string escaping. You are loading your regex within `""` quotes, instead of the `//` literal syntax, so you need to escape any `\` characters within your quotes as `\\`.

Comment: try http://regexpal.com/ it is great for experimenting with this.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane - the fiddle shows `{2,}` in the first section, which should have 2 or more. The second one shows `{2}`, which I understood to mean it needed exactly 2.

Comment: @EmmyS When I load [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmmyS/z2fTr/), the regex is `new RegExp("[A-z]{2,}[,][A-z]{2,}")`. You have written `{2,}` *twice* there, and never used `{2}`. But in your question, you use `{2,}` once there and then `{2}` once. (Also, your test string is different: your fiddle has `var str="ab,cd";`, but your question uses `"ab,cdf"`.)

Comment: Strange. I'm looking at it now and it shows `{2}` in the second instance. Maybe I didn't save the update I made to it. Sorry.

Comment: @EmmyS Make sure that as well as clicking Update to save a new version, you click Base to save that new version as the base version. The base version is the version accessible at the URL without a version number at the end, e.g. `/EmmyS/z2fTr/` instead of `/EmmyS/z2fTr/3/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `{2,}` is at least 2, and `{2}` is exactly two, so I'm not sure why three characters after the comma are still returning true.

That's correct. What you forgot is to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your expression to string start and end - otherwise it returns true when it *occurs somewhere in* the string.

> not including any whitespace: I've tried adding the \S indicator after the comma

That's the exact opposite. `\s` matches whitespace characters, `\S` matches all non-whitespace characters. Also, you probably want some [optional repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of the whitespace, instead of requiring exact one.

> ```
> [A-z]
> ```

Notice that this character range also includes the characters between `Z` and `a`, namely `` []^_` ``. You will probably want `[A-Za-z]` instead, or use `[a-z]` and make your regex case-insensitive.

Combined, this is what your regex should look like (using a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression) instead of the `RegExp` constructor with a string literal):

```
var patt1 = /^[a-z]{2,},\s*[a-z]{2}$/i;
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I rarely have a need for regexp, so I haven't spent much time with it and the little vagaries can make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `^`,`$`.Also the range should be `[a-zA-Z]` not `[A-z]`

Your regex should be

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,}[,]\s*[A-Za-z]{2}$
```

---

`^` would match string from the beginning...

`$` would match string till end.

Without `$`,`^` it would match anywhere in between the string

`\s*` would match 0 to many space..

Comment: `[A-z]` returns true for any alphabetic characters, regardless of case. (Or seems to in my tests.)

Comment: @EmmyS it would also match `[`,\,`]`,`^`,`_`..refer to ascii table